# Getfile with multiple extension filter and order by file name

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010, vb6-migration

i am working on vb.net desktop application.now i need that files coming from directory is in with extension .txt and .sql and also need that files coming in order by folder name. in need both together  how to do it?

```
  Try
                Dim s As String = Txtfolder.Text


                Dim files As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
                Try
                  For Each f As String In Directory.GetFiles(s, "*.*").Where(Function(f1) f1.EndsWith(".sql") OrElse f1.EndsWith(".txt")).OrderBy(Function(f) f.LastWriteTime).First()
                        files.Add(f)
                    Next

                    For Each d As String In Directory.GetDirectories(s)
                        files.AddRange(DirSearch(d))
                    Next
                Catch excpt As System.Exception
                    MessageBox.Show(excpt.Message)
                End Try


  Private Function DirSearch(ByVal sDir As String) As List(Of String)
        Dim files As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
        Try
            For Each f As String In Directory.GetFiles(sDir, "*.*").Where(Function(f1) f1.EndsWith(".sql") OrElse f1.EndsWith(".txt"))
                files.Add(f)
            Next

            For Each d As String In Directory.GetDirectories(sDir)
                files.AddRange(DirSearch(d))
            Next
        Catch excpt As System.Exception
            MessageBox.Show(excpt.Message)
        End Try

        Return files
    End Function
```

Comment: You basically got two options. You can either get all files and then filter yourself, e.g. with a `Where` call, or you can make two calls and then combine the results, e.g. with a `Concat` call.

Comment: can you give example of it please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of option 1 from my comment, i.e. get all file paths and filter yourself:

```
Dim folderPath = "folder path here"
Dim filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath).
                          Where(Function(s) {".txt", ".sql"}.Contains(Path.GetExtension(s))).
                          OrderBy(Function(s) Path.GetFileName(s)).
                          ToArray()
```

Here's an example of option 2, i.e. get paths by extension and combine:

```
Dim folderPath = "folder path here"
Dim filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.txt").
                          Concat(Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.sql")).
                          OrderBy(Function(s) Path.GetFileName(s)).
                          ToArray()
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative method, which allows searching for multiple directories and filtering the results using multiple search patterns.
It returns an ordered `List(Of String)`:

```
Private Function DirSearch(ByVal sDirList As String(), SearchPatter As String()) As List(Of String)
    Return sDirList.SelectMany(
        Function(dir) SearchPatter.SelectMany(
            Function(filter)
                Return Directory.GetFiles(dir, filter, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            End Function).OrderBy(Function(xDir) xDir)).ToList()
End Function
```

You can pass the method a list of paths and a list of extensions:

```
Dim SearchPaths As String() = New String() {"[Directory1]", "[Directory2]"}
Dim ItemSearchPattern As String() = New String() {"*.txt", "*.sql", "*.jpg"}

Dim DirListing As List(Of String) = DirSearch(SearchPaths, ItemSearchPattern)
```

Extract the content of a sigle directory with:

```
Dim FilesInDir As List(Of String) = DirListing.
                  Where(Function(entry) entry.ToUpper().
                  Contains("[DirectoryName]".ToUpper())).ToList()
```

This is a case insensitive filter. Remove (`ToUpper()`) for a case sensitive one.